# Google analytics measurement protocol Queue Time doesn't work properly

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Have problem with Queue time parameter:
1. Have hit.
2. Offline action (phone call started).
3. During conversation visitor comes to site with other source. So the new session started.
4. Phone call ends and I'm sending event with qt parameter = phone call lenghth.
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-74639540-1&cid=1141561565.1464086029&uip=195.138.65.154&ea=call&ec=PROPER&el=119&qt=127
5. Event appears in GA like initiated by last session, while using qt I expect that it will put event in session that was active at the moment of phone call start.
What is the problem? Is it possible to post event to session that is not last but ended less than 4 hours as expected by "Queue Time" behaviour? Maybe I need to specify some additional parameter?

Comment: According to documentation queue time is in milliseconds. 127 milliseconds make a very short phone call, so this might be a part of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, my fault for some reason I was sure that it is in seconds. I'll try this way.